# CMD/BAT - Help determining date 36 days ago

Tags: command-line, date, batch-file

Each night I need to do work on a folder 36 days old from the current date.  I have a system that writes files to a daily structure like below.  I need to keep 35days worth on the local disk and so each night I need to archive off the 36th day.  Here is the kicker... There are approx 2 million files per day, so I cannot efficiently scan the whole 2009 folder and only move files older than 35 days.  What I need to do is though a batch script determine the path of the folder that is 36days old and then apply my archive logic.  I have scripts to determine    but having trouble doing the determination to 36 days old.  In a pinch I can use perl if there is not a batch way to do this. --Shawn

Folder structure is like this:

```
2009\07\01
2009\07\02
2009\07\03
.
.
.
2009\08\01
2009\08\02
2009\08\03
```

@EDIT:  Helen's great answer has me 99% of the way there.  My only problem is that the month and day out of the vbs is not padded with a zero which i have to deal with in the folder structure.  Does anyone have an easy way to pad in a leading 0 if the day or month is less than 10?

Here is what I am doing so far:

```
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%x in ('cscript //nologo get36thday.vbs') do (
   SET YYYY=%%z
   SET MM=%%x
   SET DD=%%y)
```

except %MM% ends up being 7 instead of 07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch way to determine the date would be too compilcated; it's much easier to use a script for that. Sorry, no Perl sample but a VBScript one:

```
WScript.Echo DateAdd("d", Date, -36)
```

You can call this script from a batch file and read the calculated date like this:

```
for /f %%d in ('cscript //nologo datediff.vbs') do set dt=%%d
```

Answer (score 1):

The batch option is pretty wicked you will need to calculate which month it is then based of of that run a while loop counting down the days. I would high recommend perl as it would be a few lines of code

using the DateTime module from CPAN

http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm

```
my $dt = DateTime->now->subtract(days => 36);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you came here with google like me:
To fix the leading zero's in the .vbs I add a zero in front and strip the right 2 characters.
"0" & "7" -> "07" and "0" & "14" -> "14"
OldDateCode.vbs:

```
OldDate = DateAdd("d", Date, -36)
DateCode = Year(OldDate) & Right("0" & Month(OldDate), 2) & Right("0" & Day(OldDate), 2)
WScript.Echo DateCode
```

I also wanted to keep the 1st folder of the month so I compare the last 2 digits (day) with "01"
VBS code to check for 1st day:

```
If Right(DateCode, 2)="01" then
  WScript.Echo "The 1st:" & vbCrLf & DateCode
Else
  WScript.Echo "Not the 1st:" & vbCrLf & DateCode
End If
```

CheckDate.bat:

```
@Echo Off
Set Folder=D:

for /f %%d in ('cscript //nologo OldDateCode.vbs') do set OldDateCode=%%d

If "%OldDateCode:~6,7%"=="01" (
  Echo "Old Backup: %OldDateCode% 1st of the month: keeping..."
) ELSE (
  Echo "Old Backup: %OldDateCode% not the 1st of the month: removing..."
  RD /S /Q "%Folder%\%OldDateCode%"
)
pause
```

Make a folder in D:\ with the datecode of 36 days ago. Play around with the -36 and the datecodes.